# Re-formatting a dataframe to show sequence number and time difference after a groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that has an identifier, a sequence number, and a timestamp.

For example:

```
MyIndex     seq_no    timestamp
1          181        7:56
1          182        7:57
1          183        7:59
2          184        8:01
2          185        8:04
3          186        8:05
3          187        8:08
3          188        8:10
```

I want to reformat by showing a sequence number for each index and with the time difference, something like:

```
MyIndex     seq_no    timediff
1          1        0
1          2        1
1          3        2
2          1        0
2          2        3
3          1        0
3          2        3
3          3        2
```

I know I can get the seq_no by doing

```
df.groupby("MyIndex")["seq_no"].rank(method="first", ascending=True)
```

but how do I get the time difference? Bonus points if you show me how to do the time difference between steps, or total timediff from the start.

Comment: Is `Index` a column or actually your index

Comment: My index, sorry for the confusion, I will rename it

Comment: Is your timestamp in format `hh:mm` or `mm:ss`?

Comment: It is a full datetime timestamp: dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to get the difference is to convert the timestamp to a single unit. You can then calculate the difference with groupby and shift.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """Index     seq_no    timestamp
1          181        7:56
1          182        7:57
1          183        7:59
2          184        8:01
2          185        8:04
3          186        8:05
3          187        8:08
3          188        8:10"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

# use cumcount to get new seq_no
df['seq_no_new'] = df.groupby('Index').cumcount() + 1

# can convert timestamp by splitting string
# and then casting to int
time = df['timestamp'].str.split(':', expand=True).astype(int)
df['time'] = time.iloc[:, 0] * 60 + time.iloc[:, 1]

# you then calculate the difference with groupby/shift
# fillna values with 0 and cast to int
df['timediff'] = (df['time'] - df.groupby('Index')['time'].shift(1)).fillna(0).astype(int)

# pick columns you want at the end
df = df.loc[:, ['Index', 'seq_no_new', 'timediff']]
```

Output

```
>>>df

   Index  seq_no_new  timediff
0      1           1         0
1      1           2         1
2      1           3         2
3      2           1         0
4      2           2         3
5      3           1         0
6      3           2         3
7      3           3         2
```

Comment: can I shift by the value of MyIndex to get the time difference with the initial. value?